# Is setting endResponse to False when calling HttpResponse.Redirect in Asp.Net Application_Error handler recommended?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, httpresponse, http-redirect

I have an Asp.Net Web Forms app running .NET Framework 4.7.2 with an Owin pipeline.

In the Application_Error handler I'm adding code at the end of the handler to redirect to a custom error page when an unhandled exception is thrown. I've read a lot of posts on this site that suggest that calling `Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx")` should suffice but the Microsoft documentation for the [HttpResponse.Redirect Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirect?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_HttpResponse_Redirect_System_String_System_Boolean_) indicates in the remarks section that:

> Redirect calls [End](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.end?view=netframework-4.7.2) which throws a ThreadAbortException exception upon completion. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance. Therefore, we recommend that instead of this overload you use the HttpResponse.Redirect(String, Boolean) overload and pass false for the endResponse parameter, and then call the [CompleteRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.completerequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Couple of questions then:

1) In the Application_Error handler is there a reason why I shouldn't redirect like the following?

```
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Other logging code etc removed for brevity

        Server.ClearError()

        Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx", endResponse:=False)
        CompleteRequest()
End Sub
```

2) In page event handlers (e.g. Page_Load), button click events etc ... is there a reason why I shouldn't call `endResponse:=False` and then `CompleteRequest()`? Or in other words, in what circumstances would you definitely want to ensure that `endResponse` was set to `True`?